# Why could Squirrel Girl access the Iron Man suit?

Tags: iron-man, marvel, squirrel-girl

In *The Unbeatable Squirrel Girl #2*, the titular Squirrel Girl tries on the helmet of an Iron Man suit and tries to take control of it. However, she finds the helmet is voice locked to Tony Stark. Tippy Toe, her squirrel companion, suggests that she try her best Stark impression, but Squirrel Girl has another idea:

[image: panel 1]

[image: panel 2]

The phrase in the first panel is obviously a play on Victor von Doom (a.k.a. Doctor Doom), but I have no idea what it means. And I don't know why the suit recognized her since the only interaction Stark had had with Squirrel Girl before was shown earlier in the comic, where she just told her that she would become his "pard".

So why could Squirrel Girl access the Iron Man suit?

Comment: Any idea what "pard" means? In the context I would guess it to mean friend or something similar. Is that correct?

Comment: @maguirenumber6 I'm fairly certain that it's intended to be slang for "partner".

Comment: Of course, yes. Thanks :-)

Comment: Good to know that she is 89% curvier than Tony is.

Comment: Doesn't Squirrel Girl have Unlimited Plot Powers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, Squirrel Girl has an explicit history with Tony Stark in Marvel Super-Heroes vol. 3, #8 where she saves him from Doom (specifically from his flying doomship).  From that Tony owes her a "favor", originally getting her into the Avengers, but as she never follows up on this, one can assume she is using an emergency passcode Tony set up back then and promptly forgot (considering he has purposely mind wiped himself at least once since then it is not surprising).

She has been in and out of Marvel comics since 1992, with plenty of implied history with other characters (the offscreen relationship with Wolverine springs to mind) as well as the time spent as nanny to Danielle Cage during the "heroic age" and "fear itself" runs.